# How much time passed between Anakin turning Sith and the fight on Mustafar?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

How much time passes between Anakin becoming a Sith and his fight with Obi-Wan on Mustafar?

In the movies it makes it seem like no time at all.

Comment: "We estimate it was ... [some time.](http://theforce.net/swtc/Pix/given/fg/cass1.jpg)"

Answer (score 7):

- **Anakin became a Sith right after he helped Palpatine kill Mace Windu:**

  > “You must learn to cast off the petty restraints that the Jedi have tried to place upon your power,” he said. “Anakin, it’s time. I need you to help me restore order to the galaxy.”
  >   ...
  >   Sidious said, “Join me. Pledge yourself to the Sith. Become my apprentice.”
  >   ...
  >   “You have found it, my boy: I can feel you there. That cold distance—that mountaintop within yourself—that is the first key to the power of the Sith.”
  >   ...
  >   On the mountain peak within himself, he weighed Padmé’s life against the Jedi Order.  It was no contest. He said, “Yes.”
  >   “Yes to what, my boy?”
  >   “Yes, I want your knowledge.”  ... “I want your power. I want the power to stop death.”
  >   ...
  >   “The Jedi betrayed you,” Anakin said. “The Jedi betrayed both of us.”
  >   “As you say. Are you ready?”
  >   “I am,” he said, and meant it. “**I give myself to you. I pledge myself to the ways of the Sith. Take me as your apprentice. Teach me. Lead me. Be my Master**.”
  >   ...
  >   “What of the other Jedi?”
  >   “Leave them to me. After you have finished at the Temple, your second task will be the Separatist leadership, in their ‘secret bunker’ on Mustafar. When you have killed them all, the Sith will rule the galaxy once more, and we shall have peace. Forever.
  >   “Rise, Darth Vader.”
  >   **The Sith Lord who once had been a Jedi hero called Anakin Skywalker stood**, drawing himself up to his full height
  >   *("Revenge of the Sith" novelization, Chapter 17, "The Face of the Dark")*

  Let's call this event Day 1.
- Right after that Anakin goes to destroy Jedi in the Temple
- **Several hours after that, he sees Padme**. This is morning, so this is Day 2.

  > Senator Amidala had spent the better part of these predawn hours simply staring over the city, toward the plume of smoke that rose from the Jedi Temple; now, at last, she might get some answers.
  >   ...
  >   He dropped the electrostatic tissue and shuffled as quickly as he could to the bedroom door. “My lady,” he called to Senator Amidala, where she stood by the broad window. “On the veranda. A Jedi starfighter,” he forced out. “Has docked, my lady.”
- Now, the book **interweaves the events** - making it appear that Anakin is on Mustafar killing the CIS leaders **at the same time** as Palpatine is announcing the Empire in the Senate, **at the same time** as Yoda and Obi-Wan are in the Jedi Temple looking for recall beacon.

  All 3 story threads start and stop and change between each other in Chapter 19 "The face of the Sith" - meaning they were supposed to be happening simulateously.

  This is also confirmed, because Palpatine fights Yoda on the same exact day:

  > “Why, Master Yoda, what a delightful surprise! Welcome!” The voice of the shadow hummed with anticipation. “Let me be the first to wish you **Happy Empire Day**!”

  (Empire Day is the day of the Senate speech).
- Yet, we know that this only happened hours (meaning less than a day) after Anakin led the clone troopers to storm the Temple right after becoming Sith:

  > Thousands of clone troops swarmed the Jedi Temple.
  >   Multiple battalions on each level were not just an occupying force, but engaged in the long, painstaking process of preparing dead bodies for positive identification. The Jedi dead were to be tallied against the rolls maintained in the Temple archives; the clone dead would be cross-checked with regimental rosters. All the dead had to be accounted for.
  >   This was turning out to be somewhat more complicated than the clone officers had expected. **Though the fighting had ended hours ago**, troopers kept turning up missing.
- After watching the recording in the Temple, Obi-Wan comes to visit Padme. C-3PO notes that it's only been a day since Anakin left:

  > When was the last time you saw him? Do you know where he is?”
  >   C-3PO’s photoreceptors registered the Senator’s flush as she lowered her eyes and said, “No.”
  >   Three years running the household of a career politician stopped C-3PO from popping back out and **reminding the Senator that Master Anakin had told her just yesterday he was on his way to Mustafar**; he knew very well that the Senator’s memory failed only when she decided it should.

  So this is Day 3.
- Again, the duels of Obi-Wan vs. Anakin and Yoda vs Sidious are shown in interweaving narrative in Chapter 20 "Chiaroscuro" - which implies they were happening at the same time.

  **So, Mustafar fight also happened on Day 3, meaning less than 2 days after Anakin turned into a Sith; but defintely more than 1 full day (since we have several hours of morning for Padme to watch burning Jedi Temple; yet Obi-Wan only visits her the day after)**

Answer (score 0):

It's not really well-defined when exactly Anakin becomes a Sith because it's more of a process than an instantaneous thing.   But if you take it as being when he slays the younglings and Sidious calls him Vader, this is slightly before Obi-Wan views the security recordings with Yoda.  Obi-wan then he immediately talks with Padme, then they go to Mustafar.  It seems to be right away,  but we technically don't know whether the flight time is hours or days.   However there doesn't appear to be anything else off screen besides the flight.